# Most cost-effective way to purchase individual bonds?

Tags: bonds, fees, broker

I am trying to determine the most cost effective way to go about purchasing individual corporate and municipal bonds that I intend to hold until maturity.

Is there great variation in the fees and commissions across brokers?

Is there any reason not to use a platform designed for active traders?  I intend to make at least one trade per month.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive Brokers is the best for me for plain vanilla stuff including bonds - not so for options, sxxxs for that. Sure there are many others, but IB is what I use, and have no complaints aside of their extremely clunky platform. I'd recommend them.